# Is there any property of a neutrino that prevents it from being considered the missing monopole that will make Maxwell's equations symetric

Tags: maxwell-equations, magnetic-monopoles, leptons

The zero in Gauss's magnetic law, is it an approximation?

Could it be in reality be a really tiny number like the magnetic field strength of a neutrino?

Neutrinos are members of the Lepton family that contains only the three flavored neutrinos and the electron and its more massive forms the muon and tau. That would make the monopole particle a long range force carrier like gravity when compared to it's more massive cousin the electron and the shorter range electrostatic force.

The article below is the one that got me looking for a monopole candidate.

*There is one zero that is present in Maxwell's equations, which shows up in Gauss's magnetic law. As you know, zero means the absence of something - that which does not exist. And this particular zero means that magnetic monopoles do not exist.

In Gauss's law for electric fields, we see that the divergence of the electric flux density is equal to the volume electric charge density. However, when we take the divergence of the magnetic flux density, the result is not equal to the volume magnetic charge density.

Why?

Since the discovery of Maxwell's equations and modern physics, physicists have been trying to find the magnetic monopole. A finding would make Maxwell's equations much more symmetric. If electric charge exists and gives rise to electric fields, and magnetic fields also exist, why do magnetic charges (monopoles) not exist?

No one has a good explanation, and to this day physicists are looking for them. But this zero, this all-important zero, is a declaration that they have not been found. Magnetic dipoles do exist (as in magnets with a north and south pole), but no matter how many times you break a magnetic dipole it will never form two monopoles - you'll just get smaller magnetic dipoles.

Magnetic charge is measured in Webers. This equation has the units of weber/meter^3 (magnetic charge density), so this zero is measured has units of [Wb/m^3].*

[Link to Original Article](http://www.maxwells-equations.com/zero.php)

Comment: *"Magnetic charge is measured in Webers."* No. It's not. The Weber is a unit of magnetic *flux*. And the magnetic flux density is $\mathrm{Wb/m^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Magnetic monopoles are of huge interest because if found they would (a) explain the quantization of charge and (b) offer some really cool technological possibilities.

And they are easily detected, and experimental searches have been carried out.

Neutrinos on the other hand are pouring through the Earth in their uncounted trillions every second of every day. And they don't trigger the monopole detectors. In fact they are a royal pain to detect at all.

So, no. There is no way. And a site which suggests that there might be should be treated as nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

The CERN monopole detector the "Monopole & Exotics Detector at the LHC" is looking for highly ionizing stable massive particles and haven't found any real Maxwell law changing monopoles.

The magnetic force is a long range force so if it has a quantatizing unit it must be small like an electron but because it hasn't been observed it can't be a one to one ratio between the two it would be a million times less massive and carry a feeble magnetic charge. Just like our hard to observe Neutrino which shows up in every change in momentum of the electron and it's cousins the muon, tau's & anti-particles.

So if it doesn't conflict with some conservation property in quantum chromodynamics or string theory maybe an experiment design is more in order which was the more elegant answer I was looking for rather than a nonsense shutdown.